# MongoDB - couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, caused by :Connection refused : connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:374:17

Tags: mongodb, homebrew

I installed mongodb with homebrew and i use Mac OS Big Sur
when I start mongo db with

```css
$ brew services start mongodb-community
```

It says that mongodb it successfully started but when i run

```css
$ brew services list
```

The status of mongodb-community is "error" and if I try to type the command "mongo" in the cmd it gave me the problem explained in the title of this question:

```
MongoDB shell version v4.4.3
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:374:17
@(connect):2:6
exception: connect failed
exiting with code 1
```

Comment: check mongo service log file and see if the server has started or not.

Comment: How can i check this file?

Comment: [check here for log file path](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/#installing-mongodb-4-4-edition-edition)

Comment: when i try /opt/homebrew/var/log/mongodb it returns no such file or directory

Comment: check log file path in mongod.conf file. location of .conf file is also mentioned in the above link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran the following in command line to fix the problem.

```
mongod --dbpath /usr/local/var/mongodb
```

this was directly after a re-install.

The error message that clued me in was:

> {"t":{"$date":"2021-04-22T11:33:48.608-04:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":20557,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"DBException in initAndListen, terminating","attr":{"error":"NonExistentPath: Data directory /data/db not found. Create the missing directory or specify another path using (1) the --dbpath command line option, or (2) by adding the 'storage.dbPath' option in the configuration file."}}

more specifically

> "error":"NonExistentPath: Data directory /data/db not found. Create the missing directory or specify another path using (1) the --dbpath command line option, or (2) by adding the 'storage.dbPath' option in the configuration file."

Answer (score 0):

if you want to run mongodb type on terminal:

```js
mongod --dbpath /usr/local/var/mongodb
```

If it not works use only:

```js
mongod
```

And if you want to make CRUD in your db via SHELL or TERMINAL, run this :

```js
mongo
```

Answer (score -1):

```
-Archlinux
```

Search for `[.mongodb / mongosh /]`

Give execute permission to config.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you **edit** your answer to include some additional explanation? As it stands, readers not familiar with this are unlikely to be able to follow it.